# Scooby Don't - Enigmatic Puzzle

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

[image: Scooby Don't - Enigmatic Puzzle]

Clues:

**r(t)=e<sup>(t/4)</sup>**

- t<sub>1</sub> = 0
- t<sub>2</sub> = 8 ln(3)/
- t<sub>3</sub> = 2.0492
- t<sub>4</sub> = II . IV VII VII VI I

[contextual diagram]

Instructions: Name That Astronaut


_ _ _ _ A

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Taking out my calculator, I find that all of the $r(t_i)$ numbers are close to integers, all within the 1-11 range that appears in the diagram.

- $r(t_1) = 1$
- $r(t_2) \approx 9$
- $r(t_3) \approx 5$
- $r(t_4) \approx 7$

So I think that the “astronaut” (or “cosmonaut”) you're looking for is:

> [**LAIKA** the dog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laika), who was launched into space by the Soviets in **1957**.  Her name satisfies the letter pattern `[AL][AI][IK][AK]A` from the boxes connected to the numbers 1, 9, 5, 7 in the diagram.

The question title is:

> a reference to [*Scooby-Doo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scooby-Doo), thus hinting at a dog.  “Don't” may be a reference to the fact that Laika never returned from space, dying of overheating while in orbit.

OP Edit:

> r(t4) is the number 2.47761 in roman numerals